# readthedocs not creating documentation from public github repository

Tags: github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a public github repository.  Following [instructions](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) at readthedocs, I used Sphinx to get the documentation in a form I'm happy for others to see.

> Edit your files and rebuild until you like what you see, then commit your changes and push to your public repository. Once you have Sphinx documentation in a public repository, you can start using Read the Docs.

I've pushed all of that to my public repository at github.  In particular, I have a `docs.py` and an `index.rst` file sitting within `docs`, which is a folder sitting in the top level of my project.

I've created my account at readthedocs.  I've told readthedocs where to find the repository.  I now expect that

> Within a few seconds your code will automatically be fetched from your public repository, and the documentation will be built.

Instead, readthedocs appears to build it, but when I go to look at it, there's just nothing there.  The webpage exists, but it doesn't have any of the documentation present.  The same file built on my computer shows the documentation.

You can see the output from the build at readthedocs [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/epidemicsonnetworks/builds/5247491/).

One more detail that may be relevant is that I had to edit the `conf.py` file at github so that it knows that the main code is in the directory that `docs` sits in.

So - what do I need to change to get readthedocs to correctly build my documentation, and more importantly, what have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTD cannot find a module that is imported by your module. See the error by expanding the fourth item: https://readthedocs.org/projects/epidemicsonnetworks/builds/5247491/

So whatever you do locally to build the docs cannot be done on RTD until you configure RTD to find the module. There is an [FAQ that covers this issue](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc).

For Pyramid, we have a [setup.py](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/setup.py), and put the command `-e .[docs]` into a file called `rtd.txt`, both at the root level of the project. Then we configure RTD to use this file, under Advanced Settings:

- tick "Install your project inside a virtualenv using `setup.py install`"
- enter the name of your Requirements file.

See screenshot.[image]

Comment: This is making sense, but there's a lot to digest.  It looks like the issue for me is that my module requires importing networkx.  (networkx.github.io).  So it looks to me like I need to create a requirements file with a single line stating this.  I'm just not quite sure what the syntax of that would be.  Can you add that?

Comment: See documentation of [pip requirements](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html). The git section provides some syntax examples.

Comment: Just a note for others who may be doing this with something using scipy (and perhaps other common packages), you'll have to check the "Give the virtual environment access to the global site-packages dir." box

Comment: @Joel Updated my answer as requested.