# sphinx_rtd_theme is not getting applied on the ReadTheDocs builds but local builds work fine

Tags: themes, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am facing a strange problem. I added latest sphinx_rtd_theme files on to my project and did the required theme overrides (including the well-known text wrapping within the tables).

The local build works absolutely fine. But it was pushed to the master, the theme goes back to very basic and it is not getting applied. I tried manual builds but still I could not trace the root cause and the workaround.

By master, I mean the builds that are created on the ReadTheDocs website (account).

Comment: Did you follow the [RTD theme installation instructions](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme#installation) for your local repo?  If you follow those instructions correctly, as well as RTD's instructions for [webhooks](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks.html) and [Getting Started](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), then it should Just Work™.  Otherwise you must post a link to your RTD builds page to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Steve Piercy - Thanks for the reply. We have been using Sphinx for over 4 years now. The theme was ra always.  

Only recently we thought of using sphinx_rtd_theme. The local build works very well but it does not on the ReadTheDocs Repo. 

I am not sure what additional setting is required on the ReadTheDocs end for us to configure?

Comment: there is not much that anyone can do to help you without more information. Can you post a link to your RTD builds page? Here's an [example for Pyramid](http://readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid/builds/). From there, one can see exactly what happened during the build process, see what you mean by the theme going "back to very basic", and other pertinent information.

Comment: [build that did not get the sphinx_rtd_theme applied](http://readthedocs.org/projects/qubole-documentation/builds/5326805/) - it is the build.

Comment: The build indicates that you have not correctly configured your project to use `sphinx_rtd_theme` on RTD. You should follow the [package method](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme#via-package) for RTD, not the git/download method. Then make sure you configure your RTD account and your webhooks as I originally stated.

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for the tip again. I did it by installing the new theme via Package. As usual, the local build worked well but I got the [NoTheme on RTD Build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/qubole-documentation/builds/5339279/) again. Webhook is configured on bitbucket and other changes are done at the RTD account. 

Is it necessary to add anything in requirements.txt file?  I Just realized that I had forgotten to add **html_theme_options** but added the option  values.

Comment: I had a very similar issue, and solved it by following @StevePiercy's advice and adding the webhook from my github page *manually* (https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks.html) as opposed to setting it up *automatically* when registering with RTD. Prior to this, I followed all the steps detailed in https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html and https://github.com/readthedocs./sphinx_rtd_theme#installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [RTD Versions](https://readthedocs.org/projects/qubole-documentation/versions/), "latest" points to the master branch of your project's documentation. I looked at the source of [`conf.py` on the master branch](https://bitbucket.org/qubole/docs/src/391473b3587e74dbd2732e912a1b2e1455e0ea81/sphinx/conf.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#conf.py-101), and it is set to the theme `ra`. So whatever you are doing locally is not getting pushed up to the same branch that RTD uses to build docs.

Before you do anything else, make sure that any changes you make locally, push up to your organization repo, and that RTD pulls from to build the docs are all on the **same branch**.

Once you get that sorted, and assuming you want to use `rtd_sphinx_theme` both on RTD and locally, and that you also want other developers to be able to reproduce the docs, then follow the [`sphinx_rtd_theme` installation via package method](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme#via-package).

Comment: No, actually kthe conf.py that is reflecting on master has `ra` as the theme set. This is because I reverted to the old version. I change the conf.py with the sphinx_rtd_theme in a branch and then merge it with the master branch. After I push the changes, then a build gets triggerred. But that is not taking the new theme. The output that I get with the sphinx_rtd_theme does not even have `ra` theme set. It goes back to just a list of html topics (a very basic one). That is the issue.

Comment: I had answered it as soon as I got the wrong build after installing the Sphinx RTD theme via package method

@Steve - Thanks for the tip again. I did it by installing the new theme via Package. As usual, the local build worked well but I got the [NoTheme on RTD Build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/qubole-documentation/builds/5339279/) again. Webhook is configured on bitbucket and other changes are done at the RTD account. Is it necessary to add anything in requirements.txt file? I Just realized that I had forgotten to add html_theme_options but added the option values.

Comment: Rather than constantly revising your master branch, create a development for testing branch and configure RTD to build that branch as well. Then we're both looking at the same things. I can't hit a moving target.

Comment: We don't directly revise the master branch. I generally create a local branch, make the changes and then merge that with the master branch. What ever is on the ReadTheDocs is the master branch. For example conf.py is of the master branch that gets refreshed after the local branch is merged with it. 

That is why I always tell local branch's build looks okay only when the local branch gets merged with the master' RTD build, things don't work.

Comment: `conf.py` has not been updated in 2 days and it still uses the `ra` theme. RTD uses that file to configure the build of your docs. RTD will continue to use the `ra` theme until you configure it to use another, as I answered above.

Comment: I reverted to the older conf.py version as soon as I found out the HTML did not get sphinx_rtd_theme applied. Every time I try, the conf.py is updated. When I push the changes to the master branch, the build gets triggerred and the theme is not getting applied. 

So, I revert the changes and the conf.py goes back to the `ra` setting.

Comment: I cannot troubleshoot a moving target. Instead make an easily reproducible example. Configure RTD to build another branch that does not flip-flop so others can see (1) the state of the repo's branch that does not use the theme you expect, (2) how the build looks on RTD, and (3) the build log on RTD. Then provide links to that repo's branch, the RTD Builds page, and the built docs. Leave it alone to give others a chance to review and comment on it asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, These are the three branches that I created so far (merged to and reverted from the master)

[sphinx via package branch](https://bitbucket.org/qubole/docs/branch/DOC-695b#diff)
[sphinx via git download branch](https://bitbucket.org/qubole/docs/branch/DOC-695a#diff)

I will get back to you on another branch build on RTD.

Comment: This is how the build looks in the HTML when I applied the sphinx_rtd_theme to the branch that I had posted above - [Sphinx RTD Theme HTML](http://docs.qubole.com/en/doc-695b/)

Please let me know if this is helpful in figuring out the root cause.

Comment: You are missing a requirements.txt file and configuration of RTD to find it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217198/readthedocs-not-creating-documentation-from-public-github-repository/43219151#43219151

Comment: Thanks so much! 

We have a requirements file but `pip install sphinx_rtd_theme` is not added in there. Should I add it in the file?

Comment: Requirements file is already configured in the RTD account also.

Comment: You don't put `pip install foo` into a requirements file. See [requirements file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format). Then you need to push the commit of your requirements.txt file into the branch of your repo from which RTD will build the docs. I don't see one https://bitbucket.org/qubole/docs/src/05aabbe2cfafbacf5015959dfcb1b2c85542a5d3/sphinx?at=DOC-695b Is that the correct branch?

Comment: yes that's the branch that I tried to apply Sphinx RTD Theme.

Comment: There is one dependencies.pip. That is treated as the requirements file as it is configured as the Requirements file on the RTD account.

Comment: I cannot verify how you have configured RTD, so hopefully you have the path correct to your requirements file as `docs/sphinx/dependencies.pip`. Nonetheless, you omitted `rtd_sphinx_theme` in your [dependencies.pip](https://bitbucket.org/qubole/docs/src/05aabbe2cfafbacf5015959dfcb1b2c85542a5d3/sphinx/dependencies.pip?at=DOC-695b&fileviewer=file-view-default) and you need to include it. If that doesn't work, comment out in your `conf.py`: `html_static_path = ['_static']`. There is a warning in the build log saying it cannot find files from the RTD theme.

Comment: FTR, you should include links to items and not just their names, like [docs on branch doc-695b](http://docs.qubole.com/en/doc-695b/), its [build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/qubole-documentation/builds/5363764/), and specific [files on your branch in your repo](https://bitbucket.org/qubole/docs/src/05aabbe2cfafbacf5015959dfcb1b2c85542a5d3/sphinx/dependencies.pip?at=DOC-695b&fileviewer=file-view-default) to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks again. The path was not there it was just depenedencies.pip.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. But can I include the theme as ` sphinx-rtd-theme>=0.2.4` in the dependencies.pip (or the requirements.txt) file. 

I am not very active on StackOverflow. I really appreciate all the help that you provided in troubleshooting this issue. Henceforth, I will try to add appropriate links/hyperlink names so that it is easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Just use `sphinx-rtd-theme` without a version number. pip will install the latest version. A version number should be specified only when your package requires a specific version.

Comment: Sorry to get back again. I added sphinx-rtd-theme in dependencies.pip and the RTD requirements file path is sphinx/dependencies.pip (docs/sphinx/dependencies.pip fails the build) 
I ran the build on RTD, it gave the same kind of output. 

Then I commented out `html_static_path = ['_static'].` Still, nothing helped and I got the same kind of output.

Almost all workarounds come back to square one. (Little tiring....)

Comment: I got it to work. See my change history. https://github.com/stevepiercy/quobole-docs/commits/DOC-695d and final build https://quobole-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much! It finally worked after removing `html_context`. I had to create _templates/layout.html and add `def add` property to wrap the text in the tables while theme_override.css as discussed in [Issue 117](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/117)

Here is the [Correct theme](http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/index.html)

Thank you so much for all the workarounds!

Answer (score 0):

ReadTheDocs doesn't purge the build directory on every new build. I fixed it by manually cleaning all temporary files from ReadTheDocs:

- all build directories
- created content from autoapi plugins

After that, my modified RTD theme was used for new builds.

To do so I added a tag detection in conf.py. If my tag is set, it does a cleanup. You can set user defined tags in the ReadTheDocs web UI.

Comment: Thanks much! How do I clean the temporary files from the ReadTheDocs. The build is live and the documentation is always accessed by users. How do I do it?

Comment: You add a few delete instructions into the conf.py. Run it once with the tag value enabled to clean everything and then remove the tag value and then trigger the build again. It's online for only a few minutes. I needed this procedure only once.

Comment: Hi, 

I just found out the Inactive versions in the project/<project>/versions page. 

Each Inactive version has a Wipe button. Should I just wipe out the inactive versions and rebuild my master branch?