# Build failed: code error for my code in Readthedocs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to link my Sphinx documentation with Readthedocs. I can build the documentation locally in my computer but when I try to have Readthedocs automatically generate the documentation I get the following error:

```
Configuration error:
There is a programmable error in your configuration file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 368, in eval_config_file
    execfile_(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 150, in execfile_
    exec_(code, _globals)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/checkouts/latest/docs/conf.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sphinx_gallery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sphinx_gallery'
```

I have imported sphinx_gallery in my conf.py file as well as added the extension 'sphinx_gallery.gen_gallery'. My conf.py file is located here:
https://github.com/leockl/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/blob/master/docs/conf.py

And my Github project is located here:
https://github.com/leockl/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [readthedocs not creating documentation from public github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217198/readthedocs-not-creating-documentation-from-public-github-repository)

Comment: Hi @StevePiercy, thanks. I think I am one step closer now. From this [link](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc), the first paragraph says I need to "enable the virtualenv feature in the Admin page of your project". I can't seem to find this option in my Readthedocs project (https://readthedocs.org/dashboard/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/edit/). Do you know where in the Admin page I can enable the virtualenv feature?

Comment: I found the option to enable the virtualenv. But I now I am getting another error about `cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index'` (though this is still an ImportError. Based on this [link](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc), shouldn't enabling virtualenv resolve all ImportError issues?

Comment: Did you read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43219151/2214933) to the previously linked question?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did and as a result I have enabled the virtualenv based on the FAQ part in the link. Can I ask what is Pyramid and if that applies to my situation?

Comment: Do you also know what is this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/__init__.py)` telling me in my Readthedocs [build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/builds/10298341/). Perhaps this will point me to a direction. Many thanks

Comment: Pyramid here serves as an example of how to set up your repo to build on RTD. In whatever file you declare your requirements, you need to include required packages.

Comment: Thanks @StevePiercy. I have tried what was suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217198/readthedocs-not-creating-documentation-from-public-github-repository/43219151#43219151) but I am still having the same error. Because the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/__init__.py)` mentions the file `__init__.py', could it be something to do with an error in this file?

Comment: it turns out there was a bug in pip that was fixed. Here's a link to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850271/2214933

Comment: Hi @StevePiercy, thanks for keeping an eye out and getting back. Yes, I can confirm the solution worked and I can now create docs in Readthedocs. Many thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read-the-docs build fails with "cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip.\_internal.index'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846065/read-the-docs-build-fails-with-cannot-import-name-packagefinder-from-pip-in)